# Using nodes with parents instead of nodes with children in Angular UI Tree

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, tree, angular-ui-tree

I'm using [Angular UI Tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) to show a TreeView. To request all nodes to a REST API, I use restangular to return a list of nodes.

But, Angular UI Tree uses this data structure:

```
[
  { 
    "id" : 1,
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id" : 11
        }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "id" : 2,
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id" : 21
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want it to use:

```
 [
   {"id" :1, parent : ""},
   {"id" :2, parent : ""},
   {"id" :21, parent : "2"},
   {"id" :11, parent : "1"}
 ]
```

How can I do that on template?

I'm using [this](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree#unlimited-nesting-html-view-or-templates-example).

Is there any other way to request an array of nodes and to use that in UI Tree where each node is a Restangular object?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: No... sorry... I ended up transforming the last one into the first one...